# Caching results from calls to microservices

Tags: caching, microservices

Lets say I have a microservice A that is a rest service, and in this service the user can  send a request that does some kind of math calculation based on the parameters sent. This microservice A has to call a microservice B in order to get a calculation and microservice A has two steps, first a validation service that does several validations for the request, included to validate the value of the calculation has to be in some kind of range and two, a service that stores in a table the calculation got from microservice B

So, in order to validate this calculation and save it, I have the next options

1. In the validation service of microservice A, the microservice A calls microservice B to get the calculation and validates it. Then if the validation is OK, the service of microservice A that stores the calculation calls again to microservice B to get the calculation and stores it in the database table
2. In the validation service of microservice A, the microservice A calls microservice B to get the calculation and validates it. Then if the validation is OK, the calculation is passed in the request for the service of microservice A that stores the calculation. Doing this way  the service of microservice A that stores this calculation, does not have to call again to  microservice B to get the calculation

I am using option 1 to separate concerns because I think validation service has just to validate, nothing else, and I mean by this that it doesnt have to "store" in the request the calculation like is done in option 2. But in option 1, you have to call two times to microservice B and I dont know if its a bad design

Thanks

Comment: Option 1 is preferable here because Microservices B owns the data and it should have only the persistence functionality. If you choose the second option, then that will anti-pattern of microservices because you are storing the data which you are not owner also if something gets changed in the MS B database, how would MS A database knows that, so it will be inconsistency between the data.

Comment: Imagine that Microservice B does some calculations only, it does not own any table. My question is more about caching the results from some microservice like is done in option 2 in order not to call two times to the same service

Comment: Understood, then in this case you can cache at MS A and you dont't need to worry about calling MS B. But make sure you are not using application-level cache like spring-cache also make sure the calculation logic of MS B is remain same.

Comment: So, you say I can call two times to MS B in order to separate concerns and in order  validation service of MS A doesnt have to store in some way the calculation got from MS B?

Comment: No, If MS B is responsible for the only calculation then you can cache at MS A.No need to call MS B for storing the data. It depends on your domain architecture which MS is CRUD MS or which is business MS(which does not interact with DB and only perform business logic, in your case MS B).

Comment: MS A owns the table, MS B just does calculations. You agree that in validation service of MS A , caches the result of calculation somewhere? Is not this violating the single responsabiliy principle because validation service  validates and do dome caching?

Comment: Definitely not. Just consider MS B is a business MS. I think the above approach is the best way to do this. If some new Ms comes  and call MS B  for calculation for different business need then they can cache at there level.